# Can I use Ubuntu as a file server?

Tags: server, samba, files, file-server

Can I use an Ubuntu desktop system as a file server or is Ubuntu Server better suited for that, and how about the permissions per folder and file?

Sorry but this is my first time to use Ubuntu. I'm using Windows Server 2003 as my file server but I have lots of problem due to viruses and I hope Ubuntu could be my solution.